# Allow consumer app on foursquare

Tags: .net

I have created an consumer app with a back end of .NET to access with foursquare API features.
Installing the app through the web is working fine, But the issue is when using the Iphone Foursquare application when allow the created consumer application, following error message displays,
"Couldn't load this web content please try again.." and the app wont get installed.

Please tell me which step I missed in when setting up the consumer app.